# Call java code in NDK not working

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I need call java method.

```
Projekt.cpp:
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "Vypocet", "(III)I");
int vysledek = env->CallIntMethod(cls, mid, nahodne_cislo, d, n);


Main.java
public Integer Vypocet(int a, int b, int c)
    {
...........other code......
...........................
         return vysl;   
    }
```

I don't know what now? :(

LogCat write **error**: `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d`.

Answer (score 1):

In your Java code, you declare a method with a return type `Integer` (which is a class, with full name java.lang.Integer).

But then in your C++ code you look for a method with the signature `(III)I`, meaning three `int` parameters and returning an `int` value. And afterwards you use the `CallIntMethod` which also expects a method returning an `int`return type.

You can solve your problem by changing your java code to :

```
public int Vypocet(int a, int b, int c) {
    //  your code 
    return vysl;   
}
```

Another solution would be to change your C++ code to reflect the `Integer` return type, to something like this :

```
// call your java method
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "Vypocet", "(III)Ljava/lang/Integer;");
jobject intObj = env->CallIntMethod(cls, mid, nahodne_cislo, d, n);

// call the Integer.getValue() to get a native int value
jclass integercls = env->GetObjectClass(intObj);
jmethodID getVal = env->GetMethodID(cls, "intValue", "()I");
int value = jenv->CallIntMethod(integervalue, getVal);
```

Comment: Did you mean "public *int* Vypocet" for the first suggestion?